# Holomorphic functions and complex conjugation

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Suppose I have given two holomorphic functions $g,f:\mathbb{C}\backslash(-\infty,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and I know that $\overline{ g(z)}=f(z)$ for all $\vert 2-z \vert <1.$ I am wondering if one can deduce that $\overline{g(z)}=f(z)$ $\forall z\in\mathbb{C}\backslash (-\infty,1] $?

I would like to use the identity theorem for holomorphic functions, but the complex conjugate is not differentiable...

Best wishes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $U$ is a connected open set and $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic functions on $U$ such that $f(z)=\overline{g(z)}$ for all $z\in U$, then actually $f$ and $g$ are constant.  Indeed, if $f(z)=u(z)+iv(z)$ then the Cauchy-Riemann equations for $f$ say that $u_x=v_y$ and $u_y=-v_x$, while the Cauchy-Riemann equations for $g(z)=u(z)-iv(z)$ say that $u_x=-v_y$ and $u_y=v_x$.  Combined, these say that $u_x=v_y=0$ and $u_y=v_x=0$, so $f'=0$.  Thus $f$ is constant, and thus so is $g$.

So in your setting, $f$ and $g$ are both constant on $|2-z|<1$, and hence constant everywhere by the identity theorem.  It follows that $f=\overline{g}$ everywhere.